# Timer and close an application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, timer

In form1 I have a close button that opens Form2 to close the application. I want form2 close after 30 secons using timer, also my idea is to use a picturebox that will get bigger while timer is running, but I think I can handle this last part.
I put the timer in form 2, and I tried to control it from form1, but it doesn't recognize the timer. 
It is my final project. I really appreciate your help.
Thank you

Comment: post the code, please. Show the exact error message, if any, for "it doesn't recognize the error." Show what you have tried.

Comment: Sounds like an exercise. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public System.Timers.Timer MyTimer { get; set; }
    int counter;

    public Form2_Load()
    {
        MyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = 1000;
        MyTimer.Elapsed+=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
        MyTimer.Start();
    }

    void  myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (++counter == 30)
        {
            //do pic
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

If you'll have this in form2 then when you make new form2 you can handle the timer and when you do show dialog it will start the timer.

Comment: Thank you! I did a little different, but you gave me the idea, now my program works!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the timer on `Form1` if it helps. It doesn't matter on which form it is. Timers do not depend on `Forms`. You can create them programmatically without putting them on a form at all. Adding a timer to a form just gives you a handy way of setting the properties in the properties window.

---

Another option is to set the `Modifiers` property of the `Timer` to `Public` in the properties window (in the `Design` section). It will enable you to access it from the other form.